# Meteor deployed to subfolder

Tags: javascript, meteor, routes

I have some issues with getting Meteor to deploy to a subfolder like `/myapp/`. For any links or references to static content on the application that aren't formed using a router, the URLs will not resolve because they don't include the URL Prefix.

For example:

`html
<a href="/">
  <img src="/images/logo.png" alt="Site Logo" />
</a>`

This works fine if you put the image in `/public/images/` directory. But when you deploy the application to a subfolder using

`ROOT_URL=htp://localhost:3000/myapp/ meteor run`

The image will not render and the link will resolve to just `http://localhost:3000` and if you're not using a reverse proxy, you'll get an error from meteor.

Links using routes formed from routers, work fine, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I came up with is to use a template helper that calls [`Meteor.absoluteUrl`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-absoluteUrl).

```
import './banner.html';

import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

Template.App_banner.helpers({
  absoluteUrl(path) {
    return Meteor.absoluteUrl(path);
  }
});
```

And then form all links like this:

```
  <a href="{{absoluteUrl}}">
    <img alt="Site Logo" src="{{absoluteUrl "images/logo.png"}}">
  </a>
```